# Using web.config to configure multiple websites/domains

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I have several shared hosting accounts with [Newtek](http://webservices.thesba.com/windows-server-2012-webcontrolcenter/). They told me one account can be used to host several websites, but I don't know how to do that.

They said it can be done using either an *.htaccess* or *web.config* file. And since it's ASP.NET, that suggests *web.config* is the way to go.

Does anyone know how to use *web.config* to route requests for a given domain to a subfolder? I assume that subfolder would need to be set as an *application starting point*, which it appears their control center will allow me to do. I just need to associate that starting point with a particular domain.

And does this sound like a reasonable approach (shy of forking out money for a virtual server)?

Comment: There can only be one Web.config at the site root, which means the app that is configured to accept requests for a specific url.  I don't know of anyway to use configuration to redirect to another domain/url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is installed, you can create a Rule to redirect the request to a subfolder based on the domain name.

```
<rule name="site2.com" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?site2.com" />
    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/site2/" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="\site2\{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Source: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site